# Are there any concurrency issues in backing up git?

Tags: git

I've seen lots of people say you can backup git repositories by just copying them, but what happens if you are copying the repository at the same time that someone is pushing some changes up to it?

Comment: This also has implications for mirroring `bup` backups, since Bup uses Git's format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically what will happen is that you will get the complete repo at the time of copy.  If there is a partial transaction hanging around from a push at time of copy it will be cleaned up as a failed transaction, just like you had lost a network connection while pushing to a remote repository.

Comment: For backups, a nicer way of doing it is to push all branches to somewhere instead of doing a standard copy. I do this to backup my work to a flashstick:

git remote add flashstick /media/flashstick;
git push flashstick master

Answer (score 3):

If you're worried about concurrency, it should be quite safe to instead use

git clone /my/repository/location /my/backup/location

As every git repository has a complete copy of everything, it's an effective backup
which is guaranteed (at least as much as git itself is!) to be concurrency-safe

Comment: Note that this won't necessarily get the .git/config stuff, but that is mostly reproducible anyway.  If you really want it, you can just do a straight file copy on it...

Answer (score 1):

No, git's central data store is atomic, by design.

You cannot lose commits in this way, just refs.

If you lose refs they are easy to recover.

Answer (score 1):

There *might* be a problem if copying takes long time, and if you somehow first copy object database, and then refs, while somebody is updating refs (that is why `rsync://` transport is deprecated).  I think if you copy refs first and then object database (and the rest) you shouldn't have any problems.