# Why can't I push this up-to-date Git subtree?

Tags: git, git-subtree

I am using Git subtree with a couple of projects that I am working on, in order to share some base code between them. The base code gets updated often, and the upgrades can happen in anyone of the projects, with all of them getting updated, eventually.

I have ran into a problem where git reports that my subtree is up to date, but pushing gets rejected. For example:

```
#! git subtree pull --prefix=public/shared project-shared master
From github.com:****
* branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
```

If I push, I should get a message that there is nothing to push... Right? RIGHT? :(

```
#! git subtree push --prefix=public/shared project-shared master
git push using:  project-shared master
To git@github.com:***
! [rejected]        72a6157733c4e0bf22f72b443e4ad3be0bc555ce -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:***'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')
hint: before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

What could be the reason for this? Why is pushing failing?

Comment: why dont you do what git is telling you: git pull ?

Comment: Git pull has nothing to do with my question. But yes, git pull gives me an up-to-date message, as there's nothing new in the origin repo.

Comment: It sounds like the branch you are on is behind where master HEAD is at -- for example, a history of ... -> A -> B -> C where the remote master HEAD is at C but your current branch is at A (or some descendent of A unconnected to C). I would look at my git history to be sure.

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  I've been using `--rejoin` to speed up subtree pushes.  When I step through the subtree push manually, running `subtree split --rejoin`, the split subtree branch only has history back to the last rejoin, when it normally contains the entire subtree history.  For me, that's the immediate cause of non-fast-forward error.  I'm still not sure why subtree split is generating a truncated history.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

I found the answer on this blog comment https://coderwall.com/p/ssxp5q

> If you come across the "Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is
>   behind. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')" problem when you're pushing (due to
>   whatever reason, esp screwing about with git history) then you'll need to nest git
>   commands so that you can force a push to heroku. e.g, given the above example:

```
git push heroku `git subtree split --prefix pythonapp master`:master --force
```

Comment: I didn't need --force. git 1.8.2.3. I think there are some bugs around subtree right now; the original error said i needed push -f which didn't make sense to me,

Comment: How to run this command on Windows? I am getting `error: unknown option 'prefix'`

Comment: Even though it does provide a work-around, it doesn't explain the behavior.

Comment: Won't this solution (with `--force`) cause other people's changes (that they pushed earlier) to be lost? Not just recent ones, but *all* other changes (from any other host repository) back to the start of time? Tell me if I'm wrong about that. But see my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/30715198/1783475 for a safer solution using `--onto`.

Comment: True but probably most uses of subtree in this manner is a one way push to heroku. Generally heroku is not considered a defacto git repo for multiple user to push and pull from.

Comment: @klimkin  I liked this answer _because_ it was not full of complicated explanation that made my head spin.  It just worked :)

Comment: I had a hard time identifying what relationship `heroku` and `pythonapp` have in the answer. Translating this out of Heroku-specific language: `git push <your subtree's origin> \`git subtree split --prefix=Path/to/subtree master\`:master --force`

Comment: For some very weird reason this command `git push heroku `git subtree split --prefix pythonapp master`:master --force` deletes the subtree branch entirely and i don't know why

Comment: Example with an URL: `git push https://github.com/VulcanJS/vulcan-next.git `git subtree split --prefix starters/next`:main --force`
This is useful if the subtree repo is read-only but you accidentally updated it from GitHub UI for example.
In my scenario, the updates go from "monorepo -> subtree repo", never the other way around so "subtree pull" won't work as usual.

Answer (score 49):

On windows the nested command doesn't work:

```
git push heroku `git subtree split --prefix pythonapp master`:master --force
```

You can just run the nested bit first:

```
git subtree split --prefix pythonapp master
```

This will (after a lot of numbers) return a token, e.g.

```
157a66d050d7a6188f243243264c765f18bc85fb956
```

Use this in the containing command, e.g:

```
git push heroku 157a66d050d7a6188f243243264c765f18bc85fb956:master --force
```

Comment: This is a much cleaner solution. Works for me!

Comment: When I run git subtree split --prefix subtreedirectoryname master, I get fatal ambiguous argument 'master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree

Comment: This is a great solution, I just kept getting `git subtree` is not a command before. After using your solution I was able to deploy a folder to heroku instead of all my repo

Comment: Great solution and time saving

Comment: for some very weird reason this command deletes my subtree branch on a second push

Answer (score 30):

Use the `--onto` flag:

```
# DOESN'T WORK: git subtree push --prefix=public/shared project-shared master --onto=project-shared/master
```

[EDIT: unfortunately `subtree push` doesn't forward `--onto` to the underlying `split`, so the operation has to be done in two commands! With that done, I see that my commands are identical to those in one of the other answers, but the explanation is different so I'll leave it here anyway.]

```
git push project-shared $(git subtree split --prefix=public/shared --onto=project-shared/master):master
```

Or if you're not using bash:

```
git subtree split --prefix=public/shared --onto=project-shared/master
# This will print an ID, say 0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef,
# which you then use as follows:
git push project-shared 01234567:master
```

I spent hours poring through the git-subtree source to figure this one out, so I hope you appreciate it ;)

`subtree push` starts by running `subtree split`, which rewrites your commit history into a format which should be ready to push. The way it does this is, it strips `public/shared/` off the front of any path which has it, and removes any information about files that don't have it. *That means even if you pull non-squashed, all the upstream sub-repository commits are disregarded since they name the files by their bare paths.* (Commits that don't touch any files under `public/shared/`, or merge commits that are identical to a parent, are also collapsed. [EDIT: Also, I've since found some squash detection, so now I'm thinking it's only if you pulled non-squashed, and then the simplistic merge commit collapsing described in yet another answer manages to choose the non-squashed path and discard the squashed path.]) The upshot is, the stuff it tries to push ends up containing any work someone committed to the current host repository you're pushing from, but not work people committed directly to the sub-repository or via another host repository.

However, if you use `--onto`, then all the upstream commits are recorded as OK to use verbatim, so when the rewriting process comes across them as one of the parents of a merge it wants to rewrite, it will keep them instead of trying to rewrite them in the usual way.

Comment: I am recommending this answer as the one, which had helped me twice already. And description is what I needed to understand how splitting and pushing to the right place works. Thank you.

Comment: What is "project-shared"?

Comment: @ColinD "project-shared" is the name of the remote. It's a name you will have chosen when configuring the place to fetch from and push to. You can get a list of remotes with `git remote -v`.

Comment: @entheh the hours you spent into this have jsut made my day. Thanks!

Comment: I found this bug always happen when your sub repository has a directory whose name is the same as the prefix, e.g. you add the sub repository as "libxxx" into the main repository, and your sub repository itself also has a sub directory named "libxxx". In this case git will incorrectly treat commits in the sub repository as commits in the main repository and try to split them. The `--onto` option helps git to identify commits that are already in the sub repository.

Comment: Can people come to their senses?  For whatever great stuff Git does, it is immediately mitigated by the lost productivity getting it to do what you want.  Also, Git fails catastrophically for component oriented projects. It's competitors do a much better job.

Answer (score 18):

For a "GitHub pages" type app, where you deploy a "dist" subtree to a gh-pages branch, the solution might look something like this

```
git push origin `git subtree split --prefix dist master`:gh-pages --force
```

I mention this since it looks slightly different from the heroku examples given above. You can see that my "dist" folder exists on the master branch of my repo, and then I push it as a subtree to the gh-pages branch which is also on origin.

Comment: Why do I have to use `--force` here?

Comment: you can of course try without force and if you get an error, you might find it helpful. I can't quite recall what my situation was

Answer (score 6):

Had this issue, too. Here's what I did, based on the top answers:

Given:

```
#! git subtree push --prefix=public/shared project-shared master
git push using:  project-shared master
To git@github.com:***
! [rejected]        72a6157733c4e0bf22f72b443e4ad3be0bc555ce -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:***'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')
hint: before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Enter this:

```
git push <origin> 72a6157733c4e0bf22f72b443e4ad3be0bc555ce:<branch> --force
```

Note the token that is output by 'git subtree push' is used in 'git push'.

Answer (score 3):

I have encountered this problem before as well, and here is how I solved it.

What I found out was I had a branch that was not attached to the local master branch. This branch exists and its just hanging in the void. In your case, its probably called `project-shared`. Assuming this is the case and when you do a `git branch` you can see a local `project-shared` branch, then you can '*append*' new commits to your existing `project-shared` branch by doing a:

`git subtree split --prefix=public/shared --onto public-shared --branch public-shared`

The way I understood is `git subtree` will start creating new branch from `--onto`, in this case its the local `public-shared` branch. Then the branch means creating a branch, which just replaces the old `public-shared` branch.

This will keep all the previous SHA of the `public-shared` branch. Finally, you can do a

`git push project-shared project-shared:master`

Assuming that you have a `project-shared` remote as well; this will push the local *hanging in the void* `project-shared` branch to the `master` branch of the remote `project-shared`.

Answer (score 3):

This is because of the limitation of original algorithm. When handling merge-commits, the original algorithm uses a simplified criteria for cutting off unrelated parents. In particular, it checks, if there is a parent, which has the same tree. If such a parent found, it would collapse the merge commit and use the parent commit instead, assuming that other parents have changes unrelated to the sub-tree. In some cases this would result in dropping parts of history, which has actual changes to the sub-tree. In particular it would drop sequences of commits, which would touch a sub-tree, but result in the same sub-tree value.

Lets see an example (which you can easily reproduce) to better understand how this works. Consider the following history (the line format is: commit [tree] subject):

```
% git log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --pretty="%h [%t] %s"
*   E [z] Merge branch 'master' into side-branch
|\
| * D [z] add dir/file2.txt
* | C [y] Revert "change dir/file1.txt"
* | B [x] change dir/file1.txt
|/
*   A [w] add dir/file1.txt
```

In this example, we are splitting on `dir`. Commits `D` and `E` have the same tree `z`, because we have commit `C`, which undone commit `B`, so `B-C` sequence does nothing for `dir` even though it has changes to it.

Now lets do splitting. First we split on commit `C`.

```
% git log `git subtree split -P dir C` ...
* C' [y'] Revert "change dir/file1.txt"
* B' [x'] change dir/file1.txt
* A' [w'] add dir/file1.txt
```

Next we split on commit `E`.

```
% git log `git subtree split -P dir E` ...
* D' [z'] add dir/file2.txt
* A' [w'] add dir/file1.txt
```

Yes, we lost two commits. This results in the error when trying to push the second split, since it doesn't have those two commits, which already got into the origin.

Usually you can tolerate this error by using `push --force`, since dropped commits generally won't have critical information in them. In the long term, the bug needs to be fixed, so the split history would actually have all commits, which touch `dir`, as expected. I would expect the fix to include a deeper analysis of parent commits for hidden dependencies.

For reference, here is the portion of original code, responsible for the behavior.

```sh
copy_or_skip()
  ...
  for parent in $newparents; do
      ptree=$(toptree_for_commit $parent) || exit $?
      [ -z "$ptree" ] && continue
      if [ "$ptree" = "$tree" ]; then
          # an identical parent could be used in place of this rev.
          identical="$parent"
      else
          nonidentical="$parent"
      fi
  ...
  if [ -n "$identical" ]; then
      echo $identical
  else
      copy_commit $rev $tree "$p" || exit $?
  fi
```

Comment: is the bug fixed as of 2020-05-09 (Sat)? @klimkin

Comment: the bug is fixed.      see: contrib/subtree: fix "subtree split" skipped-merge bug.
https://github.com/git/git/commit/933cfeb90b5d03b4096db6d60494a6eedea25d03

Answer (score 0):

Eric Woodruff's answer did not help me, but the following did:

I usually 'git subtree pull' with the '--squash' option. It seems this did make things harder to reconcile, so I needed to do a subtree pull without squashing this time, resolve some conflicts and then push.

I must add that the squashed pull did not reveal any conflicts, told me everything was OK.

Answer (score 0):

Another [simpler] solution is to advance the head of the remote by making another commit if you can. After you pull this advanced head into the local subtree then you will be able to push from it again.

Comment: This is exactly how I solved the same problem with remote repository out of sync with the local subtree.

Answer (score 0):

You can force push local changes to remote subtree repo

```
git push subtree_remote_address.git `git subtree split --prefix=subtree_folder`:refs/heads/branch --force
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick powershell for windows users based on Chris Jordan's solution

```
$id = git subtree split --prefix pythonapp master
Write-Host "Id is: $id"
Invoke-Expression "git push heroku $id`:master --force"
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I wrote based off what @entheh said.

```
for /f "delims=" %%b in ('git subtree split --prefix [name-of-your-directory-on-the-file-system-you-setup] -b [name-of-your-subtree-branch]') do @set token=%%b
git push [alias-for-your-subtree] %token%:[name-of-your-subtree-branch] --force

pause
```