# Using git subtree to deploy a build directory

Tags: git, deployment, workflow, web-deployment, git-subtree

I'm using the Ant Build Script in my project to create a build directory called “publish”
Once I run the build and update my publish folder with the new build I add and then commit and finally push this to my remote repo on github.

Once the publish folder has been added to the project I run this command suggested by Yeoman on my local machine.

```
git subtree push --prefix publish origin deployment
```

On the initial execution it deploys my publish folder to its own branch called “deployment.”

Anytime I run the build again, add files, commit files and push files to remote repo and then run that subtree command again locally I get rejected.

```
! [rejected]        22cd5e0605fcc771615bdacbde9bd95582705c17 -> deployment (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:[org]/[repo].git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first merge the remote changes (e.g.,
hint: 'git pull') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

What's the best approach with this kind of workflow?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git subtree - subtree up-to-date but can't push](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13756055/git-subtree-subtree-up-to-date-but-cant-push)

Comment: This order of commands seems to be doing the trick!
Gonna leave this open just to absolutely make sure things are rolling smoothly.

    `git subtree pull --prefix=publish origin deployment`
    `git subtree push --prefix=publish origin deployment`

Comment: You can (and should) answer your own question ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's best to use [grunt-build-control](https://github.com/robwierzbowski/grunt-build-control) for this. Takes 10 mins to install but works like a charm and the whole deploying of the build folder to remotes becomes automatic, completely version controlled and painless.

Its now also mentioned in the [Yeoman wiki](https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/wiki/Deployment) btw.