# Deploying to heroku from git sub directory

Tags: node.js, git, heroku

I'm trying to deploy to heroku from a particular directory in my project:

I've tried this command:
`git subtree push --prefix output heroku master`

and I get the response:

*error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:intquest.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.*

Is there a way to `--force` this command?  Or what exactly am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are *sure* to replace the remote heroku `master` history with a new one, you can try something similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15623469/6309):

```
git push heroku `git subtree split --prefix output master`:master --force
```