# Deploy to Openshift webapp created with Yeoman generator-webapp

Tags: git, openshift, yeoman

How can I deploy my webapp created with Yeoman generator-webapp to OpenShift?

The generator-angular-fullstack has a great option for deploying to OpenShift.

Unfortunately the generator-webapp doesn't have an option like this, and all the examples given by OpenShift indicates that I need to git clone from the Openshift repository to my localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way to doing it.

Reading the yeoman's documentation, I've found this help about [deploying](http://yeoman.io/learning/deployment.html) witch mention the use of [`git-contrib-subtree`](https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/contrib/subtree) (I ran with difficulties installing it, because the `make install` has problems with my git path).

Then when I first try to push the subtree `/dist`, it throw me the error:

```
error: failed to push some refs to '<file>'    
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do    
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing    
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first merge the remote changes (e.g.,    
hint: 'git pull') before pushing again.
```

I tried to force `--force` but `git subtree` does't recognize this option, the work around is to perform a [nested git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13756055/git-subtree-subtree-up-to-date-but-cant-push)

```
git push origin `git subtree split --prefix dist  master`:master --force
```

Once I've forced push, I can run without errors:

```
git subtree push --prefix dist origin master
```

Because my project also incorporates `nodeJS` I've had to copy the `server.js` that came with the OpenShift original code, to my app folder and use it as a template for my node project (be careful with the line `self.app = express.createServer();` it's deprecated).
Also I've modified the `Gruntfile.js` to incorporate the `server.js` and start `node`