# Git subtree - subtree up-to-date but can't push for Windows

Tags: windows, git, git-subtree

My Subtree says it's up to date, but I can't push new files

```
git subtree pull --prefix=CASE-SENSITIVE-PATH-TO-FOLDER remote-alias master
```

I am following [Git subtree - subtree up-to-date but can't push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13756055/git-subtree-subtree-up-to-date-but-cant-push).

But need a solution that works **only** for windows. The one provided does not work.

**Error:**

> ! [rejected]          d6a4b0aef2c196a0d80177a96586dd1e6f3c8544 -> master (non-fast-forward)
>
> error: failed to push some refs to 'https://repourl/repo.git'
>
> hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
>
> hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
>
> hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
>
> hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

**Here is what I've tried**

```
git subtree split --prefix path-to-folder master
```

Executing the above code gives me the following error

**Error:**

> fatal: ambiguous argument 'master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
>   Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
>   'git  [< revision>...] -- [< file>...]'

Running both below work, they both give me the token 'd6a4b0aef2c196a0d80177a96586dd1e6f3c8544', but I am having trouble trying to figure out how to "force" the branch

```
git subtree split --prefix CASE-SENSITIVE-PATH-TO-FOLDER

git subtree split --prefix CASE-SENSITIVE-PATH-TO-FOLDER -b master
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is what worked after much digging.

Looking at @aednichols's comment I found:

```
git push <your subtree's origin> `git subtree split --prefix=Path/to/subtree`:master --force
```

so here is my bat file.

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('git subtree split --prefix CASE-SENSITIVE-PATH-TO-FOLDER') do @set token=%%a
git push https://repo/repo.git %token%:master --force
pause
```

If using something other than master add the subtree dir

```
git subtree split --prefix CASE-SENSITIVE-PATH-TO-FOLDER -b subtreedir
```