# Git force push subtree: error: unknown option `force'

Tags: git, git-subtree

I'm simply trying to force push on a subtree,
using the following command:

```
git push origin git subtree split --prefix dist gh-pages:gh-pages --force
```

and I get the following error:

```
error: unknown option `force'
```

it's strange because I followed a web page and answers here in stack overflow that are using the `--f` / `--force` parameter.

Any idea what's wrong and how I can overwrite everything and push my code to the gh-pages subtree?

Comment: I don't see that --force is an option on `git subtree`.

Comment: Are those two commands in a single line? No **;** to separate them?

Comment: @eftshift0 I tried, the error is same - `error: unknown option `force'`

Comment: have you tried `git push -f origin git subtree split --prefix dist gh-pages:gh-pages`?

Comment: @NemanjaGlumac it returns `error: unknown option "prefix"`

Comment: I am just poking in the dark now, but: `git push origin \`git subtree split --prefix dist gh-pages\`:gh-pages --force` (found similar problem and answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15623469/8815185)

Answer (score 1):

Add backticks (`) which invokes a bash "command substitution".

```
git push origin `git subtree split --prefix dist gh-pages`:gh-pages --force
```

Reference:
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html