# Why can't I push change to this up-to-date Git subtree?

Tags: git, git-subtree

I have a git subtree module called "gempak-tables" in subdirectory "gempak/tables":

```
$ git config -l | grep -i gempak
remote.gempak-tables.url=git@github.com:Unidata/GEMPAK-Tables.git
remote.gempak-tables.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/gempak-tables/*
$
```

I can't push changes to the subtree module to GitHub, however:

```
$ git subtree push --prefix=gempak/tables gempak-tables master
git push using:  gempak-tables master
X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0
To git@github.com:Unidata/GEMPAK-Tables.git
 ! [rejected]        89d8f94d010e6677f146608674cf7408eecb4a61 -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:Unidata/GEMPAK-Tables.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')
hint: before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
$
```

even though the subtree module appears to be up-to-date:

```
$ git subtree pull --prefix=gempak/tables gempak-tables master
X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0
From github.com:Unidata/GEMPAK-Tables
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
$
```

My git(1) version:

```
$ git --version
git version 1.8.3.1
```

I'm a subtree novice. Please help.

Comment: Shouldn't the update command be `git subtree pull --prefix=gempak/tables gempak-tables master` ?

Comment: @phd I added the output of your command to my inquiry. Same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is most probably given already by [Git subtree - subtree up-to-date but can't push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13756055/git-subtree-subtree-up-to-date-but-cant-push)

> I found the answer on this blog comment https://coderwall.com/p/ssxp5q
>
> > If you come across the `Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')` problem when you're pushing (due to whatever reason, esp screwing about with git history) then you'll need to nest git commands so that you can force a push to heroku. e.g, given the above example:
>
> `` git push heroku `git subtree split --prefix pythonapp master`:master --force ``

Answer (score 0):

The error you receive says that your git branch is behind. The git branch which contains the up to date subtree is not up to date.

Do a `git pull` not a `git subtree pull`

Comment: That didn't fix the problem. The "git pull" obtained the message "Already up-to-date" message and a subsequent "git subtree push --prefix=gempak/tables gempak-tables master" resulted in the same error as before.