# Deploy git subdirectory on heroku

Tags: git, heroku, git-subtree

I have to deploy a git subdirectory from a non master branch. I have looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539382/how-can-i-deploy-from-a-git-subdirectory) and to [the docs on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments#advanced-linking-local-branches-to-remote-apps), but when I issue

```
git subtree push --prefix visualizations heroku develop:master
```

I get the following error

```
error: src refspec d02911f4e410256fae0760f87f186289436ff98b:refs/heads/develop does not match any
```

And I really don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Are you sure that there are commits on the develop branch?

Comment: Yes, I have done a commit with the updated Procfile.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `git subtree push` command does not use the `localBranch:remoteBranch` syntax used in the plain `git push` to define what local branch gets pushed into what remote branch. What you might need is just to change that last parameter:

```
git subtree push --prefix visualizations heroku master
```

Since `git subtree push` creates a new commit for the subtree, and that is the one pushed, there is no need define a local branch as a source.

With the above command you are telling git to create a new subtree commit from `visualizations` and to push it to the `master` branch on the `heroku` remote.