# Heroku deploy a sub directory?

Tags: node.js, git, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a node app, but I'm running into a problem with how my code is structure. The app is git inited at the top level and it looks like:

```
App (git tracked in remote repo)
- .git
- server
- client
- plugin
- extras
```

Since Heroku needs me to push only the server directory directly with the package.json build file, I'm not sure how to setup my directory. I want it such that I can deploy heroku from the 'App/server' folder, but still git pull/push the entire app as I do now:

```
App (git tracked in remote repo)
- .git
- server (can run 'git push heroku master' for just this folder)
  - .git (?)
- client
- plugin
- extras
```

How I can achieve this the simplest? I read about git-submodules, but that seems messy and I wanted to be sure. Thank you very much from a git nub.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I think git-subtree should work:

`git subtree push --prefix server heroku master`

Additional resources:

- [How can I deploy/push only a subdirectory of my git repo to Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539382/how-can-i-deploy-from-a-git-subdirectory)
- https://coderwall.com/p/ssxp5q

Answer (score 2):

Heroku requires a `package.json` and a lockfile in the root of the repository or they will fail the deploy.

However you can set up a `package.json` in the root of the repo which installs dependencies for the subdirectories and runs their related commands.

Using yarn for example, in your case you could put an empty `yarn.lock` in the root and a `package.json` like:

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "yarn --cwd server --production=false install",
    "build": "yarn --cwd server serve"
  }
}
```

The `--production=false` [ensures that devDependencies will be installed](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install/), which otherwise wouldn't happen since `NODE_ENV` is set to `production` in Heroku's environment.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use `git subtree` to create a `heroku` branch on GitHub:

```
git subtree push --prefix server origin heroku
```

which you can then deploy to Heroku using a [Heroku Button](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-button). Just add an `app.json` and a `README.md` with the button to your server directory:

```
[![Deploy](https://www.herokucdn.com/deploy/button.png)](https://heroku.com/deploy)
```

[image: Deploy]

and let Heroku take care of the rest.

Comment: Can you please share more about how to get this button to work in a subfolder? I've got the app.json and README.md in my subfolder, but the link still tries to get app.json from the root directory

Comment: @ScottCarlson In your main `README.md`, change the button markdown to `[![Deploy](https://www.herokucdn.com/deploy/button.svg)](https://heroku.com/deploy?template=https://github.com/roninbar/kwik-e-mart/tree/heroku)` (replace `roninbar/kwik-e-mart` with your GitHub username/repo).

Comment: @ScottCarlson Alternatively, switch to the `heroku` branch in GitHub before clicking the button.