# Pushing from Eclipse to remote repository at specific location

Tags: eclipse, git, egit, eclipse-neon

I have a remote Git repository with approx. the following repository structure:

```
service1/
service1/image1/
service1/image1/docker/
service1/image1/docker/Dockerfile
service2/
service2/image2/
service2/iamge2/docker/
service2/image2/docker/Dockerfile
```

I can clone it from `https://<my-git-server>/my-project.git` to obtain a directory `my-project/` and a corresponding file structure underneath it.

My `service2` is a Tomcat server that hosts a webapp whose source code I would like to push into the same remote repository next.

Eclipse's file structure inside the project folder is approx. as follows (as is normal for Dynamic Web Projects in Eclipse):

```
my-project/WebContent/
my-project/build/
my-project/src/
```

If possible, I would like to arrive at a new repository structure for the remote Git repository as follows:

```
service1/
service1/image1/docker/
service1/image1/docker/Dockerfile
service2/
service2/image2/
service2/image2/docker/
service2/image2/docker/Dockerfile
service2/image2/eclipse/
service2/image2/eclipse/my-project/
service2/image2/eclipse/my-project/WebContent/
service2/image2/eclipse/my-project/build/
service2/image2/eclipse/my-project/src/
```

My question is: how I can specify the additional path component `eclipse/myproject`? I understand that pushing from Eclipse to `https://<my-git-server>/my-project.git` would result in `WebContent`, `build` and `src` becoming siblings of `service1` and `service2`, and that pushing from Eclipse to `https://<my-git-server>/my-project.git/service2/image2/eclipse/my-project` would not work either.

So how does one accomplish such a thing?

Comment: Perhaps Git [subtrees](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10648623/1789384), [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) or [sparse checkouts](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2303645/1789384) are the way to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further study and reflection I have decided on managing source code for my project in two Git repositories. I have no outside dependencies that would prevent me from doing so and have come to understand that [monorepos](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/10/monorepos-in-git/) and Git don't fit so well.

For reference, here are the new repository structures:

```
service1/
service1/image1/docker/
service1/image1/docker/Dockerfile
service2/
service2/image2/
service2/image2/docker/
service2/image2/docker/Dockerfile

WebContent/
build/
src/
```

If I am not mistaken, Git [subtrees or submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31770147/1789384) could now serve for cloning from these repositories into a single "mono" (as in monorepo) local view, if ever required.