# Heroku Context Auto Building with Github

Tags: heroku

Does Heroku supports context building like Openshift supports? Like, i have this repository but i want to build only inside a specific folder in github webhook. 
I coud not find anything in interface and for CLI i just could find resources using the heroku-git. It needs to be IN THE GITHUB WEBHOOK, is there anyway to do that? The method for commit to a heroku origin is not what i'm looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I deploy/push only a subdirectory of my git repo to Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539382/how-can-i-deploy-push-only-a-subdirectory-of-my-git-repo-to-heroku)

Comment: I do not think so, this is a palleative solution and works only for Heroku original (not for the github webhook).