# How to add script in package.json for deploying multiple localhosts servers in single app in nodejs heroku?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, heroku, localhost

How to add script in package.json for deploying multiple localhosts servers in single app in nodejs heroku ?
Suppose in my main project folder I have 2 game folders ( game1 (running on localhost:3000) and game2 (running on localhost:5000) ) and my main website ( running on localhost:8080).
So for running my complete project I perform 1) `node server.js` 2) `node ./game1/server.js`
3)  `node ./game2/server.js` . But while deploying project on heroku we add `"start" : "node server.js"` in scripts in package.json . So my question is how to add `"node ./game1/server.js "` this also in package.json ?

Comment: You can't do this on Heroku. Each app only gets _one_ port.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/7539382/354577 in case you want to deploy to multiple apps

Comment: @Chris i am unable to understand by this link stackoverflow.com/q/7539382/354577 can you plz explain me in short ?

Comment: If you really need three servers, deploy them to three apps. That link shows how to deploy a subdirectory to Heroku, e.g. `server.js` to one app, `game1/server.js` to a second, and `game2/server.js` to a third.