# Two people working on a file at the same time in git

Tags: git, github

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How git works when two peers push changes to same remote simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643998/how-git-works-when-two-peers-push-changes-to-same-remote-simultaneously)

I'm kinda new to git and me and a friend want to do some collaborative developing with git. I got the whole pull and push system down somewhat, now I have a question.

I want to work on file **test.php** and I pull for new changes. Nothing. I edit it and want to push it, but in this time my friend edited and pushed it. What happens now? How are these conflicts solved?

Thank you!

Comment: It's been already discussed on this site: [How Git works when two peers push changes to same remote simultaneously][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643998/how-git-works-when-two-peers-push-changes-to-same-remote-simultaneously

Comment: I'm not a `git` guy, I'm an `svn` guy, so I can't answer the question. I should point out, however, that the entire point of these version control systems is to handle the exact case you're describing. It's their *fundamental* purpose. Expect this to happen very often.

Comment: @bchetty: Nice find! Also, the link markup is different in comments: `[link text](url)`. You can click "help" to remind yourself.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

the procedure should be the below:

- pull the file
- edit it
- commit it(it commits to your local repository)
- pull it again (if there are any conflict you will Be notified) in that case you can solve it executing the below command(GitBash on your repository working folder):

  git mergetool

it will run the merging tool you got configured in your .gitconfig file

after that you can push your changes