# What does GIT PUSH do exactly?

Tags: git, git-push

I can't seem to find a good explanation of this.

I know what **git pull** does:

1) a **fetch**, i.e. all the extra commits from the server are copied into the local repo and the *origin/master* branch pointer moves to the end of the commit chain

2) a **merge** of the *origin/master* branch into the *master* branch, the *master* branch pointer moving to the newly created commit, while the *origin/master* pointer staying put.

I assume **git push** does something very similar, but I don't know for sure. I believe it does one of these, or something similar, or something else (?):

- copies all local commits and makes a merge there (the reverse of what **git pull** does); but in this case, the server does not have my local *master* branch, so I can't see what is it merging

OR

- merges my *master* branch into the *origin/master*, pushing the resulting commit to the server and linking it next to the existing end-commit, also moving the server's *master*; this doesn't seem right because then my local *origin/master* is not in sync with the server's.

I'm currently using git for basic operations so I'm doing fine, but I want to fully understand these internals.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Assuming you already understand git's "objects" model (your commits and files and so on are all just "objects in the git database", with "loose" objects—those not packed up to save space—stored in `.git/objects/12/34567...` and the like)...

You are correct: `git fetch` retrieves objects "they" (`origin`, in this case) have that you don't, and sticks labels on them: `origin/master` and the like.  More specifically, your git calls up theirs on the Internet-phone (or any other suitable transport) and asks: what branches do you have, and what commit IDs are those?  They have `master` and the ID is `1234567...`, so your git asks for `1234567...` and any other objects needed that you don't already have, and makes your `origin/master` point to commit object `1234567...`.

The part of `git push` that is symmetric here is this: your git calls up their git on the same Internet-phone as usual, but this time, instead of just asking them about *their* branches, your git tells them about *your* branches and *your* git repository objects, and then says: "How about I get you to set your `master` to `56789ab...`?"

Their git takes a look at the objects you sent over (the new commit `56789ab...` and whatever other objects you have that they didn't, that they would need to take it).  Their git then considers the request to set *their* `master` to `56789ab...`.

As [Chris K already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26005068/1256452), there is no merging happening here: your git simply proposes that their git overwrite their `master` with this new commit-ID.  It's up to their git to decide whether to allow that.

If "they" (whoever they are) have not set up any special rules, the default rule that git uses here is very simple: the overwrite is allowed if the change is a "fast forward".  It has one additional feature: the overwrite is *also* allowed if the change is done with the "force" flag set.  It's usually not a good idea to set the force flag here, as the default rule, "only fast forwards", is usually the *right* rule.

The obvious question here is: what exactly is a fast forward?  We'll get to that in a moment; first I need to expand a bit on labels, or "references" to be more formal.

### Git's references

In git, a branch, or a tag, or even things like the stash and `HEAD` are all *references*.  Most of them are found in `.git/refs/`, a sub-directory of the git repository.  (A few top-level references, including `HEAD`, are right in `.git` itself.)  All a reference is, is a file<sup>1</sup> containing an SHA-1 ID like `7452b4b5786778d5d87f5c90a94fab8936502e20`.  SHA-1 IDs are cumbersome and impossible for people to remember, so we use names, like `v2.1.0` (a tag in this case, version 2.1.0 of git itself) to save them for us.

Some references are—or at least are intended to be—totally static.  The tag `v2.1.0` should never refer to something other than the SHA-1 ID above.  But some references are more dynamic.  Specifically, your own local branches, like `master`, are moving targets.  One special case, `HEAD`, is not even a target of its own: it generally contains the *name* of the moving-target branch.  So there's one exception for "indirect" references: `HEAD` usually contains the string `ref: refs/heads/master`, or `ref: refs/heads/branch`, or something along those lines; and git does not (and cannot) enforce a "never change" rule for references.  Branches in particular change a lot.

How do you know if a reference is supposed to change?  Well, a lot of this is just by convention: branches move and tags don't.  But you should then ask: how do you know if a reference is a branch, or a tag, or what?

#### Name spaces of references: `refs/heads/`, `refs/tags/`, etc.

Other than the special top-level references, all of git's references are in `refs/` as we already noted above.  Within the `refs/` directory (or "folder" if you're on Windows or Mac), though, we can have a whole collection of sub-directories.  Git has, at this point, four well-defined subdirectories: `refs/heads/` contains all your branches, `refs/tags/` contains all your tags, `refs/remotes/` contains all your "remote-tracking branches", and `refs/notes/` contains git's "notes" (which I will ignore here as they get a bit complicated).

Since all your branches are in `refs/heads/`, git can tell that these should be allowed to change, and since all your tags are in `refs/tags/`, git can tell that these should not.

#### Automatic motion of branches

When you make a new commit, and are on a branch like `master`, git will *automatically* move the reference.  Your new commit is created with its "parent commit" being the previous branch-tip, and once your new commit is safely saved away, git changes `master` to contain the ID of the *new* commit.  In other words, it makes sure that the branch *name*, the reference in the `heads` sub-directory, always points to the *tip-most commit*.

(In fact, the branch, in the sense of a collection of commits that is part of the commit-graph stored in the repository, is a data structure made out of the commits in the repository.  Its only connection with the branch *name* is that the tip commit of the branch itself is stored in the reference label with that name.  This is important later, if and when branch names are changed or erased as the repository grows many more commits.  For now it's just something to keep in mind: there's a difference between the "branch tip", which is where the "branch name" points, and the branch-as-a-subset-of-commit-DAG.  It's a bit unfortunate that git tends to lump these different concepts under a single name, "branch".)

### What exactly *is* a fast forward?

Usually you see "fast forward" in the context of merge, often with the merge done as the second step in a `git pull`.  But in fact, "fast forwarding" is actually a property of a *label move*.

Let's draw a little bit of a commit graph.  The little `o` nodes represent commits, and each one has an arrow pointing left, left-and-up, or left-and-down (or in one case, two arrows) to its parent (or parents).  To be able to refer to three by name I'll give them uppercase letter names instead of `o`.  Also, this character-based artwork doesn't have arrows, so you have to imagine them; just remember that they all point left or left-ish, just like the three names.

```
            o - A   <-- name1
          /
o - o - o - o - B   <-- name2
      \       /
        o - C       <-- name3
```

When you ask git to change a reference, you simply ask it to stick a new commit ID into the label.  In this case, these labels live in `refs/heads/` and are thus branch names, so they are supposed to be able to take on new values.

If we tell git to put `B` into `name1`, we get this:

```
            o - A
          /
o - o - o - o - B   <-- name1, name2
      \       /
        o - C       <-- name3
```

Note that commit `A` now has *no* name, and the `o` to the left of it is found only by finding `A` ... which is hard since `A` has no name.  Commit `A` has been abandoned, and these two commits have become eligible for "garbage collection".  (In git, there's a "ghost name" left behind in the "reflog", that keeps the branch with `A` around for 30 days in general.  But that's a different topic entirely.)

What about telling git to put `B` into `name3`?  If we do that next, we get this:

```
            o - A
          /
o - o - o - o - B   <-- name1, name2, name3
      \       /
        o - C
```

Here, commit `C` still has a way to find it: start at `B` and work down-and-left, to its other (second) parent commit, and you find commit `C`.  So commit `C` is *not* abandoned.

Updating `name1` like this is *not* a fast-forward, but updating `name3` *is*.

More specifically, a reference-change is a "fast forward" if and only if the object—usually a commit—that the reference used to point-to is still reachable by starting from the *new* place and working backwards, along all possible backwards paths.  In graph terms, it's a fast-forward if the old node is an ancestor of the new one.

### Making a `push` be a fast-forward, by merging

Branch-name fast-forwards occur when the only thing you do is add new commits; but also when, if you've added new commits, you've also merged-in whatever new commits someone else added.  That is, suppose your repo has this in it, after you've made one new commit:

```
             o   <-- master
           /
...- o - o       <-- origin/master
```

At this point, moving `origin/master` "up and right" would be a fast-forward.  However, someone else comes along and updates the other (`origin`) repo, so you do a `git fetch` and get a new commit from them.  Your git moves your `origin/master` label (in a fast-forward operation on your repo, as it happens):

```
             o   <-- master
           /
...- o - o - o   <-- origin/master
```

At this point, moving `origin/master` to `master` would *not* be a fast-forward, as it would abandon that one new commit.

You, however, can do a `git merge origin/master` operation to make a new commit on *your* `master`, with two parent commit IDs.  Let's label this one `M` (for merge):

```
             o - M  <-- master
           /   /
...- o - o - o   <-- origin/master
```

You can now `git push` this back to `origin` and ask them to set *their* `master`—which you are calling `origin/master`—equal to *your* (new) `M`, because *for them*, that's now a fast-forward operation!

Note that you can also do a `git rebase`, but let's leave that for a different stackoverflow posting. :-)

---

<sup>1</sup>In fact, git references always start out as individual files in various sub-directories, but if a reference doesn't get updated for a long while, it tends to get "packed" (along with all the other mostly-static references) into a single file full of packed references.  This is just a time-saving optimization, and the key here is not to depend on the exact implementation, but rather to use git's `rev-parse` and `update-ref` commands to extract the current SHA-1 from a reference, or update a reference to contain a new SHA-1.

Comment: Real Nice Answer!

Comment: Does this mean a `git push` will always be preceded by a `git fetch`? So while pull actually only 'downloads' changes (what one would expect) a push will not only 'upload' changes but also first 'download' changes (==fetch) in order for potential conflicts to be resolved localy.

Comment: @masi: if you mean: **will** Git do a fetch before doing a push, the answer is **no**. If you mean: **should** *you* do a fetch before doing a push, the answer is often yes. Do a fetch, see what fetch did, and only then decide whether to merge, rebase, push now, or whatever. There's still a race if you use `git push --force`, which is closable through `git push --force-with-lease`, if you have some reason to force-push.

Comment: Note that **pull is not the opposite of push**. Fetch is as close as you get to an opposite, but it's not opposite either, because fetch sets *remote-tracking names* in your repository. With push, you ask the other Git to set its *branch* names.

Comment: The other key to this is to think about what could happen in the *other* Git repository, at the URL where you might fetch-or-push. Who else could fetch and/or push from/to that other Git repository? How many commits have they added since the last time you checked?

Comment: But if I don't fetch before the push and there's a merge needed at the remote, then my push will be rejected (at least by default) from the, remote, right? And (local) Git will then inform me and tell me to fetch and merge?

Comment: Right: as long as you're not doing a `git push --force`, if there are new commits in *their* repository that your `git push` would lose if they accepted it, they'll reject your `git push` as a "non-fast-forward". That is your signal that you must run `git fetch` and then incorporate their commit(s) into what you will eventually push: you can do this with `git merge` (in which case, fetch+merge = `git pull`) or with `git rebase` or however you see fit.

Answer (score 7):

It only performs a copy, no merge.

More specifically it copies the parts of the object store that are in the local repo/branch and are missing from the remote side.  This includes, commit objects, refs, trees and blobs.

Tags are a notable exception, they require the --tags flag to be included.

The following blog post, [git is simpler than you think](http://nfarina.com/post/9868516270/git-is-simpler) has more detail.

Comment: You might want to mention that it moves refs as well.

Answer (score 6):

My simplest description is, push just do the following: (assuming you do *git push origin master*)

- Copy the local commits that are not existed in the remote repo  to the remote repo
- Move the origin/master (both in your local git and in the remote git) to point to the same local/master commit
- Push DOES NOT merge

**HOWEVER**, It will check whether your local/master is based on the origin/master. Conceptually, it means in the git graph, from local/master you can go back directly to origin/master (not the origin/master of your local git, but the master on the remote repo) by only moving "downward", meaning no modification was made to remote repo before your push. Otherwise push will be rejected

Answer (score 2):

The technical, jargon-laden answer from [the manual](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) is as follows:

> `git push` "updates remote refs using local refs, while sending
>   objects necessary to complete the given refs."

So basically, it is copying information, so as to make sure your remote is up to date with your local repo. But what are refs, and what are objects? Paraphrasing the manual:

- Refs [manual entry](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-References) are files which "store the SHA-1 value [of an object, like a commit] under a simple name so you can use that pointer rather than the raw SHA-1 value" [to find the content associated with it]. You can see them by navigating to directories like `.git/refs/heads/<branch name>`, or `.git/refs/remotes/origin/<branch name>` in your repo.
- Objects ([manual entry](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-Objects)) include commits, trees, blobs, and tags (last of which are not pushed by default). As an example, quoting Mark Longair from [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643998/how-git-works-when-two-peers-push-changes-to-same-remote-simultaneously), "a commit records the exact content of the source code at that point in time with the date, author's name, and references to parent commits".

Thus, when you `git push`, git uses local refs (created by you typing `git commit`) to update equivalent files on the remote, thus updating pointers to most recent commits, and then any new content that you've created gets copied into git's system as objects, labeled with some metadata and SHA-1 refs.

**As an extra illustration of what a ref is**, [here in the Github API docs](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/refs/) they show example JSON results of API calls asking for refs in a given repo. It might help you understand how the different pieces of information relate to each other.

Answer (score 2):

Following diagram may explain it:

**Before push:**

[image: Before push]

**After push:**

[image: After push]

Git push will copy all commits from current branch that are missing in destination branch (*a38de, 893cf, 756ae*) and move the pointers both in destination branch and remote tracking branch to the same commit in local branch. Note that it will not perform any merge. Push will get rejected if it fails.