# Is Git over Network Share possible?

Tags: windows, git, network-share

Is it possible to share a Git repository in Windows network?

If I add remote origin located in windows shared folder - would this solution work normally?

Comment: Better suited for programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/751026/1301972

Comment: Yeah, it will work, I've been using it that way for a few months.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is working normally.

I used it in Windows Share without a hassle. It was not a bare repository. But I'm 99.99% sure a bare repository will work the same in a network share.
Of course, you need the read/write right on that share...

Comment: It just gets rather slow once your repository gets a decent number of files in it (in to the thousands)

Answer (score 6):

According to [a post](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/122670) in 2009 on the Git mailing list, Git *should* work seamlessly on NFS and CIFS (e.g. Windows) shares. A [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/751026/1301972) here on Stack Overflow seems to corroborate that, and explains a little more about why it should work.

You may want to do your own research, since I wasn't able to turn up anything newer than that. I also don't know anyone personally who does multi-user shared repositories over CIFS, so I'm not going to swear there are zero bugs or edge cases. With all that said, though, it certainly seems relatively low-risk.