# Git: Set up remote repository

Tags: git

I am very new to Git and having some difficulties in understanding the steps to set up a remote repository. Would really appreciate some guidance. Thanks! =)

For my case, I have been doing some projects on my PC. Right now, I want to create a shared remote repository that will be hosted on my PC so that my team mates can access from their PC. By the way, my team is connected via LAN Connection.

I am unsure if my way of doing is right. Firstly, I created a repository named GIT_Repository. Next I copied and pasted all the project files over to the folder and committed. I believe this is a local repository. How can I make it a remote repository? How can I configure the URL?

Can anyone kindly guide me? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to guide you, because there are many ways to provide access to a remote repository; what you can do about it, and how, also depends on what platform (OS) you intend to use for hosting.

At the very minimum you have to read and understand [this](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server) (but you can skip the details about setting up various software for now). You then have to evaluate the available choices, understand what platforms your team members will use to access that shared repo, do some further research and then finally try to implement a solution.

As you have provided zero info about what sort of "PCs" you team uses, I think I'll make several notes just in case:

- Access to the repo via both SSH and HTTP[S] can be implemented on Windows; it usually requires extra paint to set up, but this is doable; HOWTOs can be found on the net.
- If you run a Windows-only shop and want something dead-simple, you can just make a share out of your repo; [it works](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11240817/720999) with some care.

As to URLs used for accessing the repo, they highly depend on the access scheme, so answering this question is impossible at the moment.

Comment: Firstly, Thank you so much for replying. =D My team is using Windows XP. After some research, I understand that I would need to host my GIT repository either by own server or paid one such as GitHub (Private hosting) before I can make it a remote repository. Am I right? As we have no budget, I believe we will have to host it ourselves. Thus I'm currently looking for solution in setting up a server on my own PC as we do not have one and I'm stuck. I have both apache and Jboss installed in my PC but unsure of how to use it as a server.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few solutions to this problem on a different SO question here

[Git on a Windows Lan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230500/git-on-a-windows-lan)

From people who don't find it impossible to give advice.

Comment: Gallonallen, though we are no longer using GIT, thanks for your reply still. =)