# Switching branches and pulling and the same time

Tags: git

If you start pulling changes being on master branch, and then in other window at the same time checkout another branch, what will happen? Will Git freak out? 
It's still pulling stuff (hasn't finished yet) and then you suddenly switch the branch.

especially I'm interested on Git's behavior on Windows

Comment: why not just try it out?

Comment: This likely has your answer: [Concurrency in a GIT Repo][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750765/concurrency-in-a-git-repo-on-a-network-shared-folder