# Git Update / Clone Error: "insufficient permission for adding an object" or "refs writable by group"

Tags: git, debian, backup

I'm using an network external drive to backup my git server (a Debian system, git version 1.7.10.4).
In very short the external backup drive is mounted using

```
mount -t cifs //external/backup/drive/path /media/drive/ -o user=a_user,password=a_password
```

For new repo, my script does

```
sudo git clone --mirror file:///new_repo
```

For existing repos

```
sudo git remote update
```

Everything went OK, but recently I started to get error reports on new repos:

```
fatal: Could not make /media/drive/new_repo.git/refs writable by group
```

and on some of the old ones

```
error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database ./objects
```

I have checked consistency of user (root) read/write access among various repo, both on the server and on the backup drive

```
drwxr-xr-x 0 root root 4096 Nov 10 12:18 repo1.git
drwxr-xr-x 0 root root 4096 Nov 10 12:18 repo2.git
drwxr-xr-x 0 root root 4096 Nov 10 12:20 repo3.git
drwxr-xr-x 0 root root 4096 Nov 10 12:25 repo4.git
```

and didn't found any issue. I know files are not "group writable" but since it works for 80% of the repos, I suspect the issue is not their.

I have also checked that **core.sharedRepository** is set to **true** as suggested in related topics without success.

I suspected different rights between root (the one running the backup script) and the login used to mount the drive. But then why do I get different behavior on various repos??

Please bear with me if my question is not original enough, but I search intensively this site and the rest of the internet without success. This is really starting to drive me nuts.

With best regards

Comment: This question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750765/concurrency-in-a-git-repo-on-a-network-shared-folder addresses the main issues with using a network share to host a repository, and offers some solutions, hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks orbrey, I saw this one. However my goal is not to host my repos on a shared drive, but to make a backup copy to respect "business continuity" requirements of my customers. I could do a stupid copy (it works) but it takes ages compared to a "git remote update" :)

Comment: In that case I'd suggest setting something up in cron - maybe not just a copy (as you say it'd take ages) but maybe an incremental rsync so only the changes are copied over? You could conceivably set up a hook that would kick it off after each commit but daily (or even hourly, depending on how busy the repo is) rsyncs would keep things up to date. That way you wouldn't have to deal with the possible git/cifs issues.